# Single Sign On between Yii and Moodle two php application

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, openid, lightopenid

I have implement SOS concept between two php application. it application it available different domain like one is www.example.com and another is www.test.com.

**My required following condition.**

1.When user is login any appplication to login this user with check user name and password into mysql database table

2.After login any application username and password is not required/reenter user can directly login this application similar to Google.

3.When user logout at time both application can be logout.

-->my first application can be created Yii framework and another is moodle

please give idea to implement this concept in my both application